# Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<char,bool>'

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have to capitalize the last letter of every word.

**Input:** this is stack over flow

**Output:** thiS iS stacK oveR floW

I was trying to achieve it with the following code:

```
return String.Join(" ", s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(c => c.Last((s1 => Char.ToUpper(s1)))));
```

But it doesn't compile.

I have two errors on the statement `Char.ToUpper(s1)`

**Error 1:**

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'bool'

**Error 2:**

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
>   'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block
>   are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: The issue here is that `Last` optionally takes a *predicate*; it is "the last thing that matches {this} filter"; not "do {this} with the last thing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
var result = String.Join(" ", s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(c => c.Substring(0, c.Length - 1) + char.ToUpper(c.Last())));
```

It takes the entire substring of the word and changes the last character only.

Comment: Problem Solved !! Can you explain a bit what was the actual problem there? I could not understand the error.

Comment: There were a few, the most important one was the incorrect use of `Last`. That resulted in the major problems with conversions, etc. The call of only last resulted in a string with just the last character, so you had to take the first part as substring too.

Comment: I got it. `Last` takes a `Conditional Statement`, how stupid I am